# how to automatically repair table if crashed

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

sometimes if a table is marked as crashed, a simple

```
REPAIR TABLE `tablename`
```

works fine to continue.

how do I add an automatic repair in my PHP script?

I get the error:

```
1194 - Table 'whos_online' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get to the bottom of *why* this is happening in the first place, and fix it?

Comment: sure that would be interesting, cause it only happens about once a year to me

Comment: Were you running low on disk space when it occurred?

Comment: no, there is 6GB free

Comment: Check MySQL's [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-log.html) for clues.

Comment: I repaired it and it worked: I got the message `repair  info  Wrong bytesec: 101- 38-112 at 45112; Skipped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very unlikely to make sense.

If you need to repair tables so frequently that you need to automate it, there's something wrong with your setup. You need to fix the root cause in that case.

An automated solution would also be difficult to implement. You'd have to parse the mySQL error message to find out whether the reason your query failed is *maybe* related to a broken table. There are thousands of different possible reasons why a query could fail.

The usual way is to monitor what is going on on the web site, and having an administrator react to problems. You could, for example, have your web app send you an E-Mail when a query fails.

Comment: how can there be `thousands of different possible reasons why a query could fail.` if I the table is just **marked crashed**?

Comment: and if there is something wrong with my "standarn debian" setup, it would be interresting, but how could I find that out? (it only happens about once a year)

Comment: @rubo fair enough - in that case you'd have to check for the error message, see whether it contains "marked crashed" and run a `REPAIR` if your PHP script's mySQL user is allowed to do that. Still, if this happens so often that you feel the need to automate it, there's something wrong on your server.  (Edit: ah, you mention it doesn't happen that often)

Comment: so there is no mysql-option to try a repair automatically if that error occurs? I mean: it's stupid - mysql explains exactly what to do, but doesent do it then itself

Comment: @rubo it probably doesn't do it automatically to give the admin a chance to see there may be something wrong. A crash will always have *some* reason that may need fixing. A cron job running `mysqlcheck` could do what you want - I can't find anything about telling mySQL to do the repair automatically straight away.

Comment: So I will try `mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair`